# LINQ to XML calculation query help needed

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML file:

```
  <Price id="70">
    <Side id="111" option="1" startPrice="3.5"/>
    <Side id="222" option="2" startPrice="1.25"/>
  </Price>
  <Price id="20">
    <Side id="333" option="1" startPrice="1.25"/>
    <Side id="444" option="2" startPrice="3.25"/>
  </Price>
  <Price id="22">
    <Side id="555" option="1" startPrice="1.25"/>
    <Side id="666" option="2" startPrice="3.25"/>
  </Price>
  <Price id="23">
    <Side id="777" option="1" startPrice="2.25"/>
    <Side id="888" option="2" startPrice="3.25"/>
  </Price>
  <Price id="24">
    <Side id="999" option="1" startPrice="2.25"/>
    <Side id="000" option="2" startPrice="3.25"/>
  </Price>
```

I want to calculate each option against the other options and make the following calculations:

```
1 / ((1 / startPrice) + (1 / startPrice))
```

If the following calculation is greater than or equal to **1**, I want to get the Side IDs.

For example:

`1 / ((1 / 3.5) + (1 / 1.25))` is equal to **0.9210526315789471**, so its irrelevant for me.

The XML sometimes have 3 Side's and sometimes (like the above example) it has 2 Side's.

I have to check each option `(1/2/3)` against the other options, so if I am checking option 1, I will have to check it against option 2 or 3 (if exists), if I am checking option 2 I will have to check it against option 1 and 3, etc.

So, just a summary, the logic should be something like that:

```
Check Side ID 111 against `222, 444, 666, 888, 000.`
```

When finished, `check Side 222 against 111, 333, 555, 777, 999.`

If there are more than one options that returns a result that is higher than 1, I want to get them all, something like:

```
111 and 444
111 and 666
222 and 777
```

etc.

I thought of doing it with LINQ but it seems to be very complicated logic, so your help is needed here.

Comment: You should start from implementing your logic on standard `class` objects and then focus on parsing XML into your objects.

Comment: @IdoLazar Can you share what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - create class to hold your data and logic:

```
public class Side
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Option { get; set; }
    public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CheckAgainst(Side otherSide)
    {
        return 1 / ((1 / StartPrice) + (1 / otherSide.StartPrice));
    }
}
```

Next - get sides from your xml:

```
var sides = xdoc.Descendants("Side")
                .Select(s => new Side {
                    Id = (int)s.Attribute("id"),
                    Option = (int)s.Attribute("option"),
                    StartPrice = (decimal)s.Attribute("startPrice")
                 }).ToList();
```

And finally - filter out sides which you need:

```
var result = from side in sides
             from otherSide in sides.Where(x => x.Option != side.Option)
             where side.CheckAgainst(otherSide) > 1
             select new { side, otherSide };
```